# Blurry product card image - rendered is 486x452 vs 300x279 in real image. Smaller versions being autocreated and served using srcset

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images

I'm a noob making my own website. It's pretty much ready but only now I noticed that my product card images are very perceptibly blurry. This happens even with all my CSS turned off. My theme is **Shoptimizer**. This is their demo https://shoptimizerdemo.commercegurus.com/

Using Inspect, I noticed it's because on my screen the image is stretched to **486x452** pixels and is **300x279** pixels in reality. Unfortunately my website is still on localhost so I can't share a link yet but here is it's HTML:

```
<img width="300" height="278" src="https://localhost/Raquet%C3%AAnis/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/GX-Dynamic-Front-Case-IMPROVED-300x278.webp" class="gallery-image" alt="" srcset="https://localhost/Raquet%C3%AAnis/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/GX-Dynamic-Front-Case-IMPROVED-300x278.webp 300w, https://localhost/Raquet%C3%AAnis/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/GX-Dynamic-Front-Case-IMPROVED-1024x948.webp 1024w, https://localhost/Raquet%C3%AAnis/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/GX-Dynamic-Front-Case-IMPROVED-768x711.webp 768w, https://localhost/Raquet%C3%AAnis/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/GX-Dynamic-Front-Case-IMPROVED-990x916.webp 990w, https://localhost/Raquet%C3%AAnis/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/GX-Dynamic-Front-Case-IMPROVED-441x408.webp 441w, https://localhost/Raquet%C3%AAnis/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/GX-Dynamic-Front-Case-IMPROVED-800x740.webp 800w, https://localhost/Raquet%C3%AAnis/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/GX-Dynamic-Front-Case-IMPROVED-150x139.webp 150w, https://localhost/Raquet%C3%AAnis/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/GX-Dynamic-Front-Case-IMPROVED-500x463.webp 500w, https://localhost/Raquet%C3%AAnis/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/GX-Dynamic-Front-Case-IMPROVED-64x59.webp 64w, https://localhost/Raquet%C3%AAnis/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/GX-Dynamic-Front-Case-IMPROVED.webp 1382w" sizes="(max-width: 360px) 147px, (max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
```

Why isn't the 441w or 500w version being used instead of the 300 one?
I have no idea how all of these different smaller versions were created.
Here is a list of all my plugins:

> Autocomplete Address for WooCommerce
>
> Brazilian Market on WooCommerce
>
> Child Theme Configurator
>
> Code Snippets Pro
>
> CommerceGurus Commercekit
>
> Custom Fonts
>
> Elementor
>
> Elementor Pro
>
> FiboSearch - AJAX Search for WooCommerce (Pro)
>
> Folders
>
> Kirki Customizer Framework
>
> MC4WP: Mailchimp for WordPress
>
> One Click Demo Import
>
> Social Media and Share Icons (Ultimate Social Media)
>
> SVG Support
>
> Tidio Chat
>
> WooCommerce
>
> WooCommerce Correios - Cálculo de Frete na Página do Produto (CFPP)
>
> WooCommerce Direct Checkout
>
> WooCommerce Direct Checkout PRO
>
> WooCommerce Tab Manager
>
> YITH WooCommerce Quick View Premium
>
> YITH WooCommerce Wishlist Premium
>
> Yoast SEO
>
> Yoast SEO Premium

I was also using Smush but deactivated it and the problem persisted.

My WooCommerce Image settings in Customize > WooCommerce > Product Images:

[image]

I also noticed that for one of them, in one of the pages, the rendered size is 486x488 and the intrinsic size is 1381x1388 so it looks perfect. Unfortunately this same image looks blurry on other pages.

**SCREENSHOT OF INSPECT OF CORRECT LOOKING IMAGE** (the one in the middle, notice how it's not blurry):

https://i.ibb.co/0MGxGVZ/image.png

**SCREENSHOT OF INSPECT OF INCORRECT IMAGE**

https://i.ibb.co/wyPXv6M/image.png

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is ultimately an issue with your theme. Your theme's template appears to be ignoring the WooCommerce setting and outputting the 300 width version. How to change that depends on your theme. The reason other sources from `srcset` aren't being used is because the `sizes` attribute is telling the browser that the image is being displayed at 300 pixels wide. You'll need to raise these issues with the developer to get support.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying!

Crap, that sucks. Is there a plugin that I could buy that takes over all this?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic here, but if you want a hands off approach you'll need to use an image hosting service that can handle generating image thumbnails on the fly, like Jetpack's Photon, Smush WP, or Cloudflare Images.